# Hibernate inheritance issue with common data not to create table

Tags: hibernate, jpa, inheritance

I have a challenge with Hibernate. I need to implement one `Table` which have data like:

```
city, country
```

These two columns are common for  `AnotherTable` as well.

Now I need a solution where we do not create a table for the common fields but when we fetch data from other table the common data should be available.

Please suggest and advice on this concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is to create entities using `InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS`.

Create first a base `entity` that contains all the common fields and make it `abstract` to prevent instantiation without extending:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@Getter
public abstract class BaseTable {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    @Setter
    private String city, country;
}
```

Then extend this class like:

```
@Entity
@Getter
public class FirstTable extends BaseTable {
    @Setter
    private String tableString;
    // + other table specific fields
}
```

(**Note** that I changed name `Table` to `FirstTable` since `Table` is a reserved word)

and

```
@Entity
@Getter
public class AnotherTable extends BaseTable {
    @Setter
    private String anotherTableString;
    // + other table specific fields
}
```

With this approach there will not be generated a separate table for common fields but all tables will contain the common fields itself.